# Nginx rewrite last not works

Tags: nginx

I have problem with rewrite url. PERMANENT works fine. but when I change to LAST - it not works. phpinfo shows old values.

http://site.com/?parent_id=10   ->    http://site.com/parent/10

```
if ($args ~ "parent_id=(.*)") {
  set $parent $1;
  set $args '';
  rewrite ^/$ /parent/$parent permanent;
}
```

It should be internal as future rewrites will convert /parent/10 to Yii framework url rules.
I rewriting old website to use YiiFramework and would like to leave old urls like they are.

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 1):

Using [IF IS EVIL](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil%E2%80%8E). Attached are some URL re-writes. Also remove the `set` etc.. no need for strings!

```
http://site.com/notes/343
http://site.com/note.php?id=343

rewrite ^/notes/(.*)$ /notes.php?id=$1 last;

http://site.com/users/BlackBenzKid
http://site.com/user.php?id=1

rewrite ^/users/(.*)$ /user.php?username=$1 last;

http://site.com/top
http://site.com/top.php

rewrite ^/top?$ /top.php last;

Complex and further

http://site.com/users/BlackBenzKid/gallery
http://site.com/user.php?username=1&page=gallery

rewrite ^/users/(.*)$/gallery /user.php?username=$1&page=gallery last;
```

To **answer your question**. You want something along the lines of:

```
rewrite ^/parent/(.*)$ /parent.php?id=$1 permanent;
```